# <eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7f593c8f4400>

Tags: web3.py, python

I cant get the privateKey and address from the mnemonic
And I cant get the address from Privatekey

```
Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
acct, mnemonic = Account.create_with_mnemonic()

print(acct.address, Web3.toJSON(acct.privateKey))
print(mnemonic)
#print(Web3.toJSON(acct.privateKey))
private_key = Web3.toJSON(acct.privateKey)
print(private_key)

print(Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic))

account = Account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key[3:-1])
print(account)
```

I get this response, how can I convert this to Privatekey and address??

```
True
0xAD6404800cEEf3c67AA69FFb0E464406aA449275 "0x6dc2b0c75a1d61537bd1fc8b4d6da04a7ad34e141c61b481fe171e197677ecab"
draft agree tent legal robust pet fossil lamp rocket egg clerk item
"0x6dc2b0c75a1d61537bd1fc8b4d6da04a7ad34e141c61b481fe171e197677ecab"
<eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7f593c8f4160>
<eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7f593c8f4400>
98de9b60345e4fca37e1e900181441219ca5214d08ee92d01493f0ea078e75ea

65
<class 'eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount'>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to get exactly? I see that you can get an address and its private key from a mnemonic.

Comment: Hi, I want to get the account.address when the privatekey is supplied and I want to get the privatekey from the mnemonic

Comment: so basically I want to turn this <class 'eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount'> into something i an work with

Comment: @Peter can you help?

Comment: I dont get privatekey and address, I only get this 
<eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7f593c8f4160>
<eth_account.signers.local.LocalAccount object at 0x7f593c8f4400>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get address from private key, you could use

```py
account = Account.from_key(private_key)

print(account.address)
```

To get private key from mnemonic, you could use

```py
account = Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic)

# get private key
print(account.privateKey)

# get address
print(account.address)
```

The default type of `privateKey` is `HexBytes`. If you want to get pure in `str` type, use this

```py
# get private key in str
print(account.privateKey.hex())
```

Comment: what format is this?
b'$\xe0\xe2}\x02n\xea\x97\xbee\xb7[x\x80\xe9\xda\xf47\xfe\xa3,\xe1F\xedR\xb3x\t\x9b\x87\xfe\xfa' and how to convert it to hexadecimal?

Comment: That is a `HexBytes` type data. I already edit the answer if you want to get it in `str`.